# Loop through JSON value and return a different value

Tags: arrays, json, loops

So I have the following JSON and I'm trying to loop through it, find the `sdate` that matches `2019-07-13 14:40:50 GMT` but return the `link` value.

What is the best way to do this?

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "data": {
        "Gallery": {
            "gallery_id": "***ID***",
            "GalleryImage": [{
                    "image_id": "***ID***",
                    "gallery_id": "***ID***",
                    "Image": {
                        "image_id": "***ID***",
                        "gallery_id": "***ID***",
                        "ImageLink": {
                            "link": "URL"
                        },
                        "Iptc": {
                            "sdate": "2019-07-11 14:40:50 GMT"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "image_id": "***ID***",
                    "gallery_id": "***ID***",
                    "Image": {
                        "image_id": "***ID***",
                        "gallery_id": "***ID***",
                        "ImageLink": {
                            "link": "***URL***"
                        },
                        "Iptc": {
                            "sdate": "2019-07-12 14:40:50 GMT"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "image_id": "***ID***",
                    "gallery_id": "***ID***",
                    "Image": {
                        "image_id": "***ID***",
                        "gallery_id": "***ID***",
                        "ImageLink": {
                            "link": "***URL***"
                        },
                        "Iptc": {
                            "sdate": "2019-07-13 14:40:50 GMT"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

My understanding is that I need to use `for` loop, something like:

```
for (var key in **ID**) {
    if (**ID*.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    }
}
```

With help from Panos K, I have the following which is working but it might not be the best way to do this?

```
let initArray = {
  "status": "ok",
  "data": {
    "Gallery": {
      "gallery_id": "***ID***",
      "GalleryImage": [{
          "image_id": "***ID***",
          "gallery_id": "***ID***",
          "Image": {
            "image_id": "***ID***",
            "gallery_id": "***ID***",
            "ImageLink": {
              "link": "LINK1"
            },
            "Iptc": {
              "sdate": "2019-07-11 14:40:50 GMT"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "image_id": "***ID***",
          "gallery_id": "***ID***",
          "Image": {
            "image_id": "***ID***",
            "gallery_id": "***ID***",
            "ImageLink": {
              "link": "LINK2"
            },
            "Iptc": {
              "sdate": "2019-07-13 14:40:50 GMT"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "image_id": "***ID***",
          "gallery_id": "***ID***",
          "Image": {
            "image_id": "***ID***",
            "gallery_id": "***ID***",
            "ImageLink": {
              "link": "LINK3"
            },
            "Iptc": {
              "sdate": "2019-07-13 14:40:50 GMT"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

function getImgLinksByDate(initArray, date){
  return initArray.data
    .Gallery
    .GalleryImage
    .filter(i=>i.Image.Iptc.sdate==date)
    .map(i=>i.Image.ImageLink.link);
}

links = getImgLinksByDate(initArray, '2019-07-13 14:40:50 GMT');

links.forEach(function (item) {
    var div = document.getElementById('divID');
  div.innerHTML += '<div>' + item + '</div>';
});
```

Comment: Try parsing the JSON with Codable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a more generic method with filter and map like this (also returns urls in array if date found twice)

```
function getImgLinksByDate(initArray, date){
  return initArray.data
    .Gallery
    .GalleryImage
    .filter(i=>i.Image.Iptc.sdate==date)
    .map(i=>i.Image.ImageLink.link);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work for me. I added a loop so that I could output it to HTML. Would you (mind taking a look? Must be a better way to do this?

Comment: @Victor looks good to me, the alternative is to use the createElement method and modify the innerHTML https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Comment: thanks. Another quick one. Is it poss to only query the YYY-MM-DD so use: getImgLinksByDate(initArray, '2019-07-13') so fetch all URL on that day regardless of the times + time zone. Maybe `substr()` somehow?.. does that make sense?

Comment: I think I have it: `return initArray.data.Gallery.GalleryImage.filter(i=>i.Image.Iptc.sdate.substr(0,10)==date).map(i=>i.Image.ImageLink.link);` seems to do the trick.

Comment: @Pankos K is there a way to also return the `sdate` in the loop ...?

Comment: @Victor yes on last line(mapping) you can make to return anything like .map(i=>{return {link: i.Image.ImageLink.link, sdate:i.Image.Iptc.sdate }}); try it !

Answer (score 1):

You can use this i have used some hard code values supposing that the value remains the same you can add check for the existence of code

Consider it as a sudo example

```js
date = "2019-07-13 14:40:50 GMT"

let a = {
  "status": "ok",
  "data": {
    "Gallery": {
      "gallery_id": "***ID***",
      "GalleryImage": [{
          "image_id": "***ID***",
          "gallery_id": "***ID***",
          "Image": {
            "image_id": "***ID***",
            "gallery_id": "***ID***",
            "ImageLink": {
              "link": "URLA"
            },
            "Iptc": {
              "sdate": "2019-07-11 14:40:50 GMT"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "image_id": "***ID***",
          "gallery_id": "***ID***",
          "Image": {
            "image_id": "***ID***",
            "gallery_id": "***ID***",
            "ImageLink": {
              "link": "***URLB***"
            },
            "Iptc": {
              "sdate": "2019-07-12 14:40:50 GMT"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "image_id": "***ID***",
          "gallery_id": "***ID***",
          "Image": {
            "image_id": "***ID***",
            "gallery_id": "***ID***",
            "ImageLink": {
              "link": "***URLC***"
            },
            "Iptc": {
              "sdate": "2019-07-13 14:40:50 GMT"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

let arr = a.data.Gallery.GalleryImage;

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i].Image && arr[i].Image.Iptc && arr[i].Image.Iptc.sdate && arr[i].Image.Iptc.sdate == date) {
    console.log(arr[i].Image.ImageLink.link)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.find()`

```js
let data = {
    "status":"ok",
    "data":{
        "Gallery":{
            "gallery_id":"***ID***",
            "GalleryImage":[
                {
                    "image_id":"***ID***",
                    "gallery_id":"***ID***",
                    "Image":{
                        "image_id":"***ID***",
                        "gallery_id":"***ID***",
                        "ImageLink":{
                            "link":"URL"
                        },
                        "Iptc":{
                            "sdate":"2019-07-11 14:40:50 GMT"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "image_id":"***ID***",
                    "gallery_id":"***ID***",
                    "Image":{
                        "image_id":"***ID***",
                        "gallery_id":"***ID***",
                        "ImageLink":{
                            "link":"***URL***"
                        },
                        "Iptc":{
                            "sdate":"2019-07-12 14:40:50 GMT"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "image_id":"***ID***",
                    "gallery_id":"***ID***",
                    "Image":{
                        "image_id":"***ID***",
                        "gallery_id":"***ID***",
                        "ImageLink":{
                            "link":"***URL***"
                        },
                        "Iptc":{
                            "sdate":"2019-07-13 14:40:50 GMT"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
};

function getLinkByDate(data, date) {
  const found = data.data.Gallery.GalleryImage.find(gi => gi.Image.Iptc.sdate === date);
  return found ? found.Image.ImageLink.link : undefined;
}

console.log(getLinkByDate(data, "2019-07-13 14:40:50 GMT"));
```